# Why would an adverb change the mood of a predicate?

Tags: adverbs, modality, mood, tense-aspect-mood

With some limited knowledge (undergrad), I am trying to understand why (what appears to be) an adverb would change a predicate from irrealis to realis. This is a really complicated question, but anything will help at this point. Here is what I am looking at (sorry about the formatting, I am still learning how to post):

- ‘Zo mw horafome rubovo,’

  zo    mw   horafo-m-e  rubovo

  3SG.M  3PL pass-PL-IRR  SIMULT.

  ‘The moment he passed them,’ or ‘in the time that he passed them’
- zo mw horafoma tuovo’

  Zo     mw   horafo-m-a    tuovo

  3SG.M  3PL pass-PL-REAL  while

  ‘As he passed them,’
- *‘zo mw horafome tuovo.’

  *Zo     mw    horafo-m-e   tuovo

  *3SG.M   3PL  pass-PL-IRR  while

  *ungrammatical

-a is the realis marker, -e is the irrealis marker, horafome/a is the verb, and tuovo and rubovo are the adverbs in question. the difference between rubovo and tuovo is that rubovo focuses on the time that action occurred, while tuovo reflects the action itself.
If anyone is curious, the language is Touo, spoken in Rendova in Solomon Islands. It is a Papuan language, though doesn't seem to have any language relatives. Very little of the language has been documented thus far.

Comment: Would _zo mw horafoma rubovo_ also be ungrammatical? If _tuovo_ “reflects the action itself”, it would make sense if it can only be used with realis actions, once which are treated as having actually taken place – it’s easier to consider something real to be ‘reflectable’ than something irreal. It seems odder to me (knowing nothing at all of the language) that _rubovo_, describing “the time that the action occurred”, should select irrealis – but the relationship between adverbs and moods is not always logical.